How do I make each item of RecyclerView start a unique Activity?
I am developing a recipes app. I want to make it so that clicking Breakfast Entrees goes to Breakfast Entrees Activity, clicking Desserts goes to Desserts Activity, clicking Drinks goes to Drinks Activity, etc. Right now, clicking any of the recipe categories takes me to Breakfast Entrees Activity.
I included below the RecipeCategories class as well as RecipeCategoriesAdapter class.
package app.android.easyvegan;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class RecipeCategories extends AppCompatActivity implements RecipeCategoriesSelectionListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Utilities.SetTheme(getSharedPreferences("Themes", 0).getInt("theme", 0));
        Utilities.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe_categories);
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.topToolbar));
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recipeCategoriesRecycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        List<String> recipeCategoriesList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.recipe_categories));
        RecipeCategoriesAdapter adapter = new RecipeCategoriesAdapter(recipeCategoriesList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipe_categories, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Themes", 0).edit();

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case 2131296477:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class));
                    break;
                case 2131296666:
                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "EasyVegan Recipes");
                    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "EasyVegan: Plant-Based Recipes App");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using"));
                    break;
                case 2131296782:
                    Utilities.changeToTheme(this, 0);
                    editor.putInt("theme", 0);
                    editor.apply();
                    break;
                case 2131296780:
                    Utilities.changeToTheme(this, 1);
                    editor.putInt("theme", 1);
                    editor.apply();
                    break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    @Override
    public void onRecipeCategorySelected(String recipeCategory)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BreakfastEntrees.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}


__________________________________________________________________________________

package app.android.easyvegan;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;

public class RecipeCategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeCategoriesAdapter.RecipeCategoriesViewHolder> {

    private final List<String> recipeCategoriesList;
    private final RecipeCategoriesSelectionListener selectionListener;

    public RecipeCategoriesAdapter(List<String> recipeCategoriesList, Context context) {
        this.recipeCategoriesList = recipeCategoriesList;
        selectionListener = (RecipeCategories) context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecipeCategoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_categories_recycler,parent,false);
        return new RecipeCategoriesViewHolder(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecipeCategoriesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String recipeCategory = recipeCategoriesList.get(position);
        holder.recipeCategory.setText(recipeCategory);
        holder.recipeCategory.setOnClickListener(view -> selectionListener.onRecipeCategorySelected(recipeCategoriesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recipeCategoriesList.size();
    }

    public static class RecipeCategoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView recipeCategory;
        public RecipeCategoriesViewHolder (@NonNull TextView itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recipeCategory = itemView;

        }
    }
}

I've tried adding a 'when' statement in the onBindViewHolder for each position, but if that is the solution, I don't know how to correctly code that.
I know in the OnRecipeCategorySelcted I have it coded to start only BreakfastEntreesActivity. I'm just not sure how to adjust that to start a different Activity for each Recipe Category.

In your BindViewHolder you have to set onClickListener to start a new activity related to the item clicked.
Here is the code from my app's adapter if you are using a list to display items in your recyclerView, which is working completely fine.
public class RecipeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView recipeImageView;
    TextView recipeNameTextView;
    TextView recipeTimeTextView;
    ConstraintLayout recipeItem;

    public RecipeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        recipeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeImageView1);
        recipeNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeNameTextView1);
        recipeTimeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeTimeTextView1);
        recipeItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeItemSample);
    }
}

@Override
public RecipeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item_recipe, parent, false);
    return new RecipeViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecipeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Recipe recipe = recipeList.get(position);
    holder.recipeNameTextView.setText(recipe.getName());
    holder.recipeTimeTextView.setText(recipe.getCookingTime());
    holder.recipeImageView.setImageResource(recipe.getImageUrl());

    holder.recipeItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int selectedRecipeId = recipeList.get(position).getId();
            Intent intent = new Intent(fragment.requireContext(), RecipeDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("recipe_id", selectedRecipeId);
            fragment.requireContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

In my case, the item's parent layout is Constraint layout.
Also, I'm using recyclerView in a fragment.
If you want, I can share the full code of the adapter.

Actually yeah if you could share your full code, that would be great!

Never mind, sorted it out. Thank you!
